# Copiar datos de una Tabla Mysql a otra desde java ¿Alguien sabe como?

Tags: java, mysqldb

Tengo una base de datos de Usuarios ya creada con la Tabla Usuarios(nombre,apellido,edad),lo que quiero es mover los datos(nombre,apellido,edad) de un usuario a otra tabla que tiene la misma estructura(nombre,apellido,edad),todo esto desde Java.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante realizar preguntas en base a el documento [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), **te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado**. No olvides realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Comment: Las tablas tienen la misma estructura? están en la misma base de datos? Tal vez hasta la estructura de tu tabla nos permitiria ayudarte de mejor manera.